# installing apache httpd server on RHEL-6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, apache-httpd, load-balancing

I have 5 systems running Apache tomcat server. For load balancing, I need to install Apache httpd server. How should I do this? Please provide me some useful links and your opinions on this.

I am using RHEL6.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `httpd` package?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the standard repositories.

```
 $ sudo yum install httpd
```

After installation the configuration files are installed to `/etc/httpd`.

#### For example

```
$ ls /etc/httpd/
conf/    conf.d/  logs/    modules/ run/
```

All your configuration changes should be done inside the `conf.d` directory.